# How to mute the application in Win XP?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0

Currently, I am using the following code to mute my application:

```
[DllImport("winmm.dll")]
public static extern int waveOutSetVolume(IntPtr h, uint dwVolume);

private void mute()
{
    waveOutSetVolume(IntPtr.Zero, 0);
}
```

In Windows 7 it works but in windows XP it mutes the entire system and not only the application. How can I mute only the application in windows XP?

The WebBrowser control is the one generating the sound in my application (for example, if it plays a video).

Comment: The ability to change the volume on a per-application basis was new in Win7, IIRC, so it's not possible to do it in WinXP

Comment: Is it at least possible to disable sound in the web browser control?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/60456/Mute-WebBrowser-control

Comment: That will only disable the click sounds and not sound from flash player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shamelessly posting an answer stolen from Thomas Levensque's comment:

The ability to change the volume on a per-application basis was new in Win7, IIRC, so it's not possible to do it in WinXP

Comment: It was new in Vista, not Win7.